# Count multi-line patterns in file

Tags: bash, text-processing

I am looking for a way to search for a multi line pattern across a file.

For example, say this list of numbers was my input file:

```
3
2
5
4
8
2
5
4
2
4
2
5
4
```

If I wanted to search for instances of lines 2-4 (inclusive), I would like the result to be:

```
3
```

Since that is the amount of times those particular lines are exactly repeated. I would also like this to work with any given amount of lines, as well as any given line number range in the file.

Comment: If it's inclusive then only the value in line 3 is repeated three times. The values in lines 2 and 4 are repeated four times.

Comment: @NasirRiley I think they are asking for a multi-line grep, i.e. `2\n5\n4`

Comment: I really can't tell what OP is looking for.  Is it possible to reword it in simpler terms?

Comment: What @Sparhawk said is correct - I am looking for something like a multi line grep.

Comment: Is the input to this script "lines 2 through 4" or is it "the sequence of numbers 2,5,4"?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - this input would be 'lines 2 through four'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [pcregrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pcregrep), which is available in most distros. The following command matches a fixed string.

```
pcregrep -Mc '^2\n5\n4$' input.txt
```

#### Explanation

From the man page, pcregrep is "a grep with Perl-compatible regular expressions."

- `-M`: match the regex over multiple lines
- `-c`: output the number of matches (count), instead of the matches themselves
- `^2\n5\n4$`: regex for 2, 5, 4, each on a separate line.

## Pattern from specific lines instead

Later comments in the question suggest that the pattern to be matched is not a fixed string, but instead a general "lines 2 through 4". Here, you can use command substitution to parse the lines from the input file instead.

```
pcregrep -Mc "^\Q$(sed -n 2,4p input.txt)\E$" input.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `tail -n+2 input.txt`: output the file, from line 2 inclusive
- `head -n3`: only output the first three lines
- `\Q...\E`: *quote* the `...` part for a basic string matching as opposed to regexp matching (assumes the output of the command doesn't contain `\E`).

Note that it assumes the last lines of the output of `sed ... input.txt` are not empty as command substitution (`$(...)`) strips *all* trailing newline characters.

Comment: `sed -n 2,4p input.txt` is I think more clear than the tail|head pipeline, and simpler to plug in the start and end line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -l -0777pe '$_=()=/^2\n5\n4$/mg' input_file
3
```

Working:

- `-0777` => slurp mode, meaning read the whole file in.
- `-p`    => before reading the next record, print the current record, `$_` to stdout.
- `-l`    => set the RS = ORS = "\n"
- the regex `/^2\n5\n4$/mg` is implicitly applied on the `$_`, which in our case is the whole file remember. the `/m` regex modifier shall match the line endings and beginnings too apart from string beginnings and string endings. `/g` modifier will get all the matches in the `$_` aka the whole file.
- We do this in the list-context, and assign it to an empty list. The $_ thus gets re-assigned with the number of elements in the list, which is the number of times the regex matched really.

HTH

Comment: Without hardcoding the pattern, you can pass the start and end lines of the file and extract it within the perl code: `perl -s -l -0777pe '$p = join "\n", (split /\n/)[$start-1 .. $end-1]; $_ = ()=/^${p}$/mg' -- -start=2 -end=4 input_file`

Comment: Thanks @glenn jackman, for providing the generalization.

Answer (score 0):

Your post doesn't mention any requirement for regular expression support, so I'm going to assume that you will be searching for fixed, literal text strings.

This probably isn't the fastest algorithm you've ever seen, but it works, if you have enough time.  It has the slight defect that if there are more than one N-line patterns that begin with the same first line and have the same SHA256 hash, it will give incorrect results.  It assumes that all possible N-line patterns will have unique SHA256 hashes.

It will be tediously slow on large files, especially those which contain numerous occurrences of the first line of the pattern.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# What's the name of the list file?
LIST=list

# What's the name of the pattern file?
PATTERN=pattern

# We'll figure out how many times the pattern lines appear (consecutively) in the list.

# Where's your SHA256 tool?
SHA256=/sbin/sha256

# what's the first line of pattern?
PATTERN_START="$(head -1 $PATTERN)"

# where in the list does that single line appear (what line numbers?)
START_LINES="$(grep -nx "$PATTERN_START" $LIST | sed -e 's/:.*//')"

# how many lines long is the pattern?
PAT_LEN="$(grep -c  ^ < $PATTERN)"

echo Pattern is $PAT_LEN lines long, and might start at any of these lines:
echo $START_LINES

PAT_HASH="$($SHA256 < "$PATTERN")"

# So how many times does $PATTERN appear consecutively in $LIST?
PAT_COUNT=0

for LINE in $START_LINES
do
        HASH="$(tail +$LINE $LIST | head -$PAT_LEN | $SHA256 -q)"
        if [ "$HASH" = "$PAT_HASH" ]
        then
                echo match at line $LINE
                PAT_COUNT=$(($PAT_COUNT+1))
        fi
done

echo The pattern was found $PAT_COUNT times
```

The output:

```
$ cat list
3
2
5
4
8
2
5
4
2
4
2
5
4
$ cat pattern
2
5
4
$ . foo.sh 
Pattern is 3 lines long, and might start at any of these lines:
2 6 9 11
match at line 2
match at line 6
match at line 11
The pattern was found 3 times
```

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
mpc() {
    # mpc: multiline-pattern counter
    # the first argument $1 is the first line number to include in the pattern
    # the second argument $2 is the last line number to include in the pattern
    # the third argument $3 is the input file

    line_count=$(( $2 - $1 + 1 ))
    multiline_pattern=$(head -n $2 "$3"| tail -n $line_count)
    awk -v RS='' -v FPAT="$multiline_pattern" '{print NF}' "$3"
}

# count how many times multiline-pattern defined by lines 2 to 4 (inclusive) occurs
mpc 2 4 input_file
```

Requirement:

The second argument must be at least equal to or greater than the first argument. I make no guarantee to the output if you violate that.

Disclaimer:

This doesn't work if characters `\` and/or `$` appear in any of the lines included as a pattern. `awk` struggles to process those characters as parts of a pattern even if they're backslash-escaped.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
a="2 5 4"; tr '\n' ' '  < test | grep -o "[^0-9]$a[^0-9]" | wc -l
```

With the separator of your choice....

You need the regex to prevent a match in the event of .... `22 5 44` ... or similar